# CSS Background-Image Tag

Tags: html, css

So I have created a simple html file with a CSS page linked to it.  I am trying to put an image entitled "texture.png" as that background.  It is contained within the file "images" while the "CSS" folder contains the CSS page.  Both of these folders containing the necessary files are within the same folder.  Because we are within the CSS folder I thought we needed to go out of the CSS folder and tell it to go into the images folder.  This is what I had:

```
body {
background-image: url("../images/texture.png");
background: black;
}
```

I was pretty sure that the .. at the beginning of the url would work, but still it would not work.  Any idea of any solutions?

Comment: Please describe your folder structure clearly, from what you mention the code should have no problem

Comment: I have a Homework folder.  It contains the following: index.html, and assets folder.  Within the assets folder there is a CSS folder, an images folder, and a javascript folder.  the image is in the images folder and the css file is in the css folder. @AngYC

Comment: You can try to use absolute path first in the meanwhile: `url('/assets/images/texture.png');`

Comment: Hmmm. Still not working.  Very strange.  I can ask my professor tomorrow but I don't see any reason why what I had would not work.

Comment: As mentioned by @Chiru below, you should remove your background properties because it overrided `background-image`, use `background-color` instead

Comment: Gosh, my apologies guys.  Been looking at my computer too long.  So obvious.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It will always take the last condition you apply. Here you apply the last condition as color not the image, so it was always taking color.

Try:

```
body {
background: black;
background-image: 
url("http://yourdomain.com/images/texture.png");
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a4rrgnz6/)

Comment: Still no luck!!

Comment: Nice catch, I overlooked it into `background-color` and thought it was just a color before the image loaded

Comment: Yeah I noticed that as you answered it!  I had applied a black background just to style the rest of it appropriately and forgot to delete it.  Been looking at my computer way too long haha.  Thank you!

Comment: Accepting + upvoting answers will be the good impact on readers. If my answer helped you out please mark as accepted + upvote it, else comment for issues

Answer (score 0):

May it helps!

```
body {
background-image: url("../images/texture.png");
background-color: black;
}
```